# IBM i SQL - dump plan cache

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I run heavy query on IBM i. First time it takes a long time, Subsequent times are much faster. It seems to be creating temporary index.  How can I remove this index, so I can re-test like the first time?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Visual Explain (VE) tool in the Run SQL Scripts component of ACS to see the differences between runs.

If indeed the issue is a system maintained temporary index (MTI), you can track it down via the schema's tooling in ACS and delete it if you so desire.

However, an MTI only gets deleted by the system when the system reboots (IPL).

So if you seeing differences without rebooting the server, I suspect the differences are caused by `psuedo-closing`.  By default, once the DB see's the same query a few times (3 is the default), instead of hard closing it's cursors, it will psuedo-close them.

Again, VE will show "hard opens" and "pseudo opens".

To get the pseduo closed cursors to hard close, simply disconnect and reconnect.